# Encryption and Tiny Data

Tags: cryptography

I have a requirement to sign a tiny amount of data (and store that signature in a similar tiny space) - standard PKCS signatures are way too big, I need something in the region of an 8 - 16 byte signature. Secondly I need it to be an asymmetric crypto, and thirdly, I need it to be *relativly* secure (not breakable in 5 minutes with todays computers).

I was hoping to:

1. Produce a hash of the data using a CRC algorithm (either CRC32 or CRC64) which would produce me 4 or 8 bytes of hash data.
2. Then encrypt that data with a private key, and append the results on the end.

Using RSA encryption however, RSA produces an output which is as long as the key minimum - so a 512 RSA key would produce 64 bytes of data. What other options are there?

*EDIT: By asymetric crypto I mean I can't have any shared-secret, i.e. there is a signing 'server' which is going to have one secret, and a distributed public application which needs to verify that the data has come from that origin so can't contain the signing secret.*

Comment: How long is the amount of data you need to sign?

Comment: If you can link several messages together you may think of a way to create a signature over all of them and verify that.

Comment: The data size will vary from 5 - 90 bytes, and the entire storage is 110 bytes. Unfortunatly, can't link messages together. - I'll post my solution when I have one as an edit.

Comment: For others finding this question [related](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33044/what-asymetric-scheme-provides-the-shortest-signature-while-being-secure). Nowaways you should ask such questions at [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) website, which is now fully promoted out of beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your requirements are obtainable. The closest you can get is probably with Elliptic Curve's but even then you would get an output of say 192 / 8 * 2 = 48 bytes minimum. With a 160 bit curve you could get that down to 40 bytes, but after that the security margin becomes too low. *This answer previously mentioned point compression, but that can probably not be used*.

You are much better off using a secure hash and then using only the first X bits, instead of using a non-secure hash such as CRC. With ECC 160 bits SHA-1 is the obvious choice, for such small parts of data SHA-1 will be strong enough. The idea of a secure hash is that nobody can create another message that maps to the same hash. This is not a property for functions such as CRC or Adler.

Comment: I'll take 25 bytes I reckon. Elliptic curve does seem to be the way to go for the smallest output data - After a few discussions here its been suggested that RSA isn't limited to key sizes of multiples of 256 but would go to any key size - but there are questions on its 'security' at lower sizes.... Can you explain why Im better off using only part of a secure hash then all of a insecure hash becuase this seems counter intuitive?

Comment: @olwstead Point compression is a patent minefield as far as I know. Anyway, what is the algorithm that gives you 21 byte signature with 160 bit curve? ECDSA signature is 40 bytes.

Comment: Hmm, you may be right. I thought you could use point compression on the output, but I'm currently thinking I'm confusing it with the public point W which can be compressed. The we would be back on double figures, say 40 bytes for ECDH 160. Still substantially better than RSA with similar properties though, even if you use message recovery.

Comment: Note that is you are going for this solution that X9.62 output will wrap the resulting signature data in a DER encoded structure. You may have to remove that set each each of the two components to the key size to have the minimal result. This would remove the 6 bytes additional overhead.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution based on digital signatures with message recovery

Let's assume that the message *M* you want to store can be split into two segments: M<sub>1</sub> and M<sub>2</sub>, and that *M = M<sub>1</sub>||M<sub>2</sub>*.

In general, the verification step in a message recovery scheme will tell you if *M* is authentic, but it will also give you back one segment (for instance *M<sub>2</sub>*) so that you effectively need to store only the other segment (for instance *M<sub>1</sub>*). As a drawback, you cannot access *M<sub>2</sub>* without verifying the signature first, but in most cases that is really not what one wants to do.

Intuitively, some storage can be used for *both* a part of the message *and* a part of the signature.

The most widespread example is probably the scheme standardized into ISO 9796-2 (which is not totally secure! Read below...). In that scheme, a 2048 bit RSA signature coupled to SHA-1 can be used to store 234 bytes of *M<sub>2</sub>*. In practice, that means that the signature length varies from 20 to 256 bytes, depedening on the length of *M*.

More specifically, if ***n*** is the length of your RSA key and ***h*** is the length of the hash output (both in bits), the number of bytes you can store in the signature is ***(n-h-16)/8***.

Whether it is good or not for you depends on how long your data is.

The caveat I mention above is that [Coron, Naccahe, Tibouchi, and Weinmann](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/203.pdf) recently showed that ISO 9796-2 can be broken more easily that one would expect, even though not "in 5 minutes on one computer" (they had to resort on several EC2 instances). Yet, it may be good enough for you security wise.

Other message recovery schemes exist, but one thing you should pay attention to is their patent status. For instance, PSS-R, [Naccache-Stern](http://www.di.ens.fr/~stern/data/St86.ps), Nyberg-Rueppel, [Pintsov-Vanstone](http://www.certicom.com/index.php/ecc-and-digital-postage-marks-part-2) cannot be freely used.

#### Solution based on signatures with appendix

[DSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) is a possibility. In this case, the signature does not embed any part of the original message. The general rule is that if you want a security of ***s*** bits, you need a ***4s*** bit long DSA signature. To say, for 80 bit security (equivalent to 2TDES) you need 40 bytes. The same formula applies for [ECDSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA), but DSA is simpler and more widespread in software libraries.

In both cases (DSA and ECDSA), the signing server **must** have a good source of randomness. If the random generator is not reliable (e.g. if the server is a Virtual Machine or an embedded system), DSA and ECDSA could be broken, no matter how long the signatures are.

Comment: So what we're saying is I can delete part of my message and use the freed-up space for the sig, and use the sig to recover. The 255 rsa example - this is 254 bytes of M2/sig so I still need space for my M1? Out of interest, If 'M1' is pre-agreed (but not secret), does that mean the 2048 bit signature is effectively the encrypted message?

Comment: @mchicago, yes I am saying you can delete part of the message. I edited the answer to give the generic way to compute the number of bytes you can embed in the signature. If M1 is pre-agreed, it doesn't need to be signed, does it?

Comment: Heh - I'm marking the EC curve answer as the right one because it gets me the closest : however, this one is certainly the more interesting. The problem is though that I need the original message to be in the plain and readable - deleting (part of) it, and using the sig to recover is probably just a long winded way of saying 'encrypt the thing' - which I think is the other main alternative.

Comment: @mchicago Sure, in that case I agree message recovery gets in the way. However, you are probably better of with good old DSA than with elliptic curve. The size of the signature is the same for the given level of security, but the software library is much simpler and surely patent free.

Comment: That depends on the software library. With Java + Bouncy Castle provider. ECDSA crypto is pretty easy to get going. Standard DSA with sizes over 1024 is not.

Comment: Good call about that randomness, but you might have created a separate answer instead of appending it to your previous solution. I can only +1 once for a single answer too :)

Answer (score -2):

Your requirements are self-contradictory.

> to sign a tiny amount of data

which presumably a secure digest (hash)

> I need it to be an asymmetric crypto

but this is reversible therefore not a secure digest.

> Using RSA encryption however, RSA produces an output which is as long as the key minimum

Using *any reversible enctyption* produces an output which is as long as the key minimum.

If you only need a hash, then use a salted md5 (16 bytes).

Comment: Not sure that they are contradictory:
 * the data size is tiny in that it is only a few bytes long
 * A hash on its own is not necessarily a signature: but it needs to be checked, so a hash is not a signature - hash(unencrypted data + shared secret) is a signature. 

However, thats a *shared* secret where i need the secrets to be asymmetric so presumably you create a hash using something like a crc, then encrypt that crc using asymmetric. A salted MD5 does not meet the requirements of no-shared secret (let me clarify that in the original post)

Comment: @symcbean I think it is you that gets all the algorithms mixed up here, not the asker. Even the part about the key is absolutely wrong, just take AES-256, which has a block size of 128 bits.

Comment: True - but why would you ever use AES to sign data?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the whole statement is incorrect, there is simply no reason why that would be the case. Of course, for signatures, there is a relation between the security of the key and the output size, I'll give you that.